# How can I know if a SQL select query from Java to SQL Server didn't return any results?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to know if a `SELECT` query made from Java to SQL Server doesn't return any results, because I'm trying to do a "verification" in the database to know if a `User` already exists, so if the `SELECT` query returned `false`, for example, I know that the given `user` doesn't exist and I can add it to the database.

```
Connection c = ConexionSQL.Conexion.getConection();
try {
    Statement select = c.createStatement();
    ResultSet r = select.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id="+id);

    if(r.next()) {
        //Show message that the user already Exists
    }
    else {
        //Add user to the database
    }
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("No se puedo realizar el select");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? The code you show already does what you want. You'll need to explain why it doesn't work for you or why you want a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your code works, but instead of using `r.next()` you can use `r.isBeforeFirst()`, because if there's data, you won't have to backtrack to get it back.

In summary, `isBeforeFirst()` returns false if there cursor is not before the first row or if there are no rows.

Comment: `isBeforeFirst()` is optional for `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` result sets, so relying on this is not a good idea as it can throw `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`